# ¿Cómo crear un objeto a partir de los valores de otros objetos que están dentro de un arreglo?

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente arreglo

```js
    [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "nombre": "Blanco"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "nombre": "Rosado"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "nombre": "Tinto"
        },
    ]
```

y a partir de él necesito generar uno que quede de la siguiente forma:

```
{ 1: "Blanco", 2: "Rosado", 3: "Tinto" }
```

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado hasta el momento? Recuerda que tu pregunta no debe parecer un [ticket para desarrollo](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433). Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 1):

Lo puedes lograr con un reduce, en el cual vas agregando cada propiedad y y cada valor.

```js
const data = [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "nombre": "Blanco"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "nombre": "Rosado"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "nombre": "Tinto"
        },
    ];
    
const transformed = data.reduce((acc, e) => ({
   ...acc,
   [e.id]: e.nombre
}), {});

console.log(transformed)
```

Answer (score 0):

así, cortesía de [copilot](https://copilot.github.com/)

```js
// function create_array([{id,nombre},{id,nombre},{id,nombre}]) to {id:name,id:name,id:name}
function create_array(array){
  var new_array = {};
  for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++){
    new_array[array[i].id] = array[i].nombre;
  }
  return new_array;
}

let resutado = create_array([ { "id": 1, "nombre": "Blanco" }, { "id": 2, "nombre": "Rosado" }, { "id": 3, "nombre": "Tinto" } ]); 
console.log(resutado);
```

Explicación: entra un array multidimensional sale uno de una sola dimensión.

Comment: No olvides [edit] tu respuesta y explicar el funcionamiento del código. Recuerda además que [es.so] _no es un repositorio de código_.

Comment: no hay mucho que explicar, entran varios sacos de información y sale uno

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    nombre: "Blanco",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    nombre: "Rosado",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    nombre: "Tinto",
  },
];
const res = data.map((item) => ({
  [item.id]: item.nombre,
})).reduce((acc, item) => ({ ...acc, ...item }), {});
console.log(res);
```